CronJob Kubernets(v1.29.4): Automatic Trigger of CronJob after settings change
I'm currently facing an issue using helm.
I've written a value template that contains a CroneJob, as follows:
...
custom_pipeline:
  schedule: "0 21 * * *" 
  steps:
    - name: test-cj
      volume: True # True or False mount in "/app/persistent"
      mountPath: "/app/ccc/"
      image: test_cj
      tag: "0.0.0"
      env:
      - name: DEBUG
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: test-cj-config
            key: DEBUG
...

When i make changes to the values of the CroneJob (custom_pipeline) and I apply them with:
helm upgrade --install test-cj . --values=./helm_values/values_test_cj.yml -n test-cj

The CroneJob is automatically triggered even if i have specified a fixed schedule.
Changed the restartPolicy settings, it didn't worked.
The current Helm template used is as follows:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name  }}-custom-pipeline
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  schedule: {{ .Values.custom_pipeline.schedule | default "0 0 * * 1" | quote }}
  concurrencyPolicy: {{ .Values.cron_job_concurrencyPolicy | default "Allow" | quote }}
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
          {{- range $index, $step := .Values.custom_pipeline.steps }}
          {{- if or $step.volume (not (eq ($step.volume | toString) "<nil>")) }}
            - name: {{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ $step.name }}-data
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: {{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ $step.name }}-data-claim
          {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if or .Values.imagePullSecrets (eq (.Values.imagePullSecrets | toString) "<nil>") }}
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regcred
          {{- end }}
          hostNetwork: true
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
          initContainers:
          {{- range $index, $step := .Values.custom_pipeline.steps }}
            - name: {{ $.Release.Name  }}-{{ $step.name }}
              image: "{{ default "mydockerhub/" $.Values.custom_registry }}{{ $step.image }}:{{ default "latest" $step.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: Always

              {{ if or $step.volume (not (eq ($step.volume | toString) "<nil>"))}}
              volumeMounts:
              - name: {{ $.Release.Name  }}-{{ $step.name }}-data
                mountPath: {{ default "/app/persistent" $step.mountPath}}
              {{ end }}

              {{ if $step.env }}
              env:
                {{- toYaml $step.env | nindent 14 }}
              {{ end }}
          {{- end }}
          containers:
            - name: {{ .Release.Name  }}-job-done
              image: busybox
              command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo "custom pipeline completed"']
          restartPolicy: Never
{{ end }}


Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The values.yaml fragment is just configuration; what does the actual Helm template that produces the CronJob look like?

Sure! Now i've included the helm template code.

This behavior is expected, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/63371
The only thing you can do is to set .spec.startingDeadlineSeconds field to something small like 200 seconds. In this case the cronjob won't run if updated more than 200 seconds after the configured schedule.

Thanks, I'll try this out.
Also do you have any suggestion on how to avoid the deletion of completed jobs? It seems that only the last one remains visible on the dashboard.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits

Thanks!
Just to let you know, I've implemented the solution you've suggested and it works just fine!

Please mark the answer as accepted them
